# How to convert a String into an Int in a Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int

If I have a list of strings containing both numbers and words, how would I turn the numbers into ints and keep the words as strings still in the list?

for example, this:

```
badList = ['56','45','01','cat','64','dog']
```

would become:

```
badList = [56, 45, 01, 'cat', 64, 'dog']
```

Comment: It is unclear, whether you want the original list to be altered (without creating a new list) - this is what your written text says, or whether you want a new list which is modifyed.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a one-line list comprehension

```
good_list = [int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for item in bad_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be by using string.isdigit()

```
good_list = []
for element in bad_list:
    if element.isdigit():
        good_list.append(int(element))
    else:
        good_list.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop

```
goodList=badList[:]
for i in range(len(goodList)):
    if(goodList[i].isdigit()):
        goodList[i]=int(goodList[i])
```

Comment: with this solution, you are altering the "goodList" - this might or might not be intended... (the op is not specific about this)

Comment: Do you want to say I am altering the "badList"?

Comment: no, you are altering the goodList and add an additional label badList. goodList and badList are both pointing to the same data structure in memory. Just add 
`print(goodList, badList)
badList.append("demo")
print(goodList, badList)` for a quick demonstration of the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert everything to `int` and catch any errors that aren't of type `int` and append them as a string like this:

```
badList = ['56','45','01','cat','64','dog']
goodList = []

for o in badList:

    try: goodList.append(int(o))

    except ValueError: goodList.append(str(o))
print(goodList)
```

Comment: Fyi, using exceptions in places where an if/else does the same job is an [anti pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)

Comment: @ArneRecknagel thanks but the link you gave me doesn't work

Comment: Strange, I chose an archived link in order for it *not* to break. This is the original: http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Comment: @ArneRecknagel  Yeah that one works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use exceptions, you could try:

```
bad_list = ['56','45','01','cat','64','dog'] 
good_list = []
for item in bad_list:
    try:
        good_list.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        good_list.append(item)
print(good_list)
```

BTW: I fixed the variables according to the common python naming conventions...